# Why is VS Code unable to convert this List into a Int?

Tags: python, arrays, types

```
def load_matrix():
matrix = sys.stdin.read()
matrix = matrix.strip().split('\n')
matrix = [row.split(' ') for row in matrix]
for m in matrix:
    matrix=[int(l) for l in m] 
print("\n Data Loaded Sucessfully")
print("\n")
var=pd.DataFrame(matrix)
return var
```

Look at this piece of code. I am trying to take a [matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75193848/how-to-take-a-whole-matrix-as-a-input-in-python) directly as the input for the program, but the read function takes the input as a list of strings. To convert it  into a int object for performing math functions, i have used the code above. running fine with online compilers but VS Code keeps throwing an error saying:

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '4\x1a'
(when given the input as:-
[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ix7t4.png)               )

From what I have researched, this happens when the value passed cannot be converted into an integer.

When I run a [similar code in Jupyter notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eb3yX.png) it runs smoothly.
Your Help will be appreciated.

Comment: *"Why is VS Code…"* It has nothing to do with VS Code.

Comment: Your for loop makes no sense. 1) you're trying to turn a list into an int, 2) you're mutating the list that you are iterating over

Comment: `\x1a` is marking the end of the file (EOF), `.strip()` doesn't remove it so you have it at the end of your string.

Comment: Well.....pls state the correct method to iterate over the loop and also as pointed out already what i want to do seems to work in Jupyter Notebook all fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed in the comments, `\x1a` is the unicode character to indicate `EOF`. I really don't know what you are trying to achieve in your code, but I can help you fix it.

In my knowledge, `x1a` takes 1 length in the `str`, so removing it would be easy as it always be at the end of the `matrix`.

```py
matrix = matrix.strip().split('\n')
matrix = [x if '\x1a' not in x else x[:len(x)-1] for x in matrix]
```

It checks for `\x1a`, if it is found, it removes it from the `matrix`.

Output (It also includes the edited `matrix`, or to be exact newly created `matrix`):

```
['1 2', '3 4']

 Data Loaded Sucessfully


    0
0   3
1   4
```

Comment: There's [`str.removesuffix`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.removesuffix) to do that on C level.